# Getting extra days from generrate_series

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I have the following command

```
select generate_series('2019-09-01'::timestamp, least(current_date, '2019-09-18'), interval '1 week')
```

which returns me back

```
2019-09-01 00:00:00
2019-09-08 00:00:00
2019-09-15 00:00:00
```

Is it possible to get last result as well even id doesn't fit specified interval?
So I'd like to get back

```
2019-09-01 00:00:00
2019-09-08 00:00:00
2019-09-15 00:00:00
2019-09-18 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could union with that final date:

```
select generate_series('2019-09-01'::timestamp, least(current_date, '2019-09-18'), interval '1 week')
union
select '2019-09-18'::date;
```

Should your generate series happen to also include the final date, the union would remove one of the two duplicates.  Otherwise, the union would include this final date.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `greatest()` in the subquery, and then `least()` in the main query :

```
select least(date, '2019-09-18') as "Date Interval"
  from
  (
   select 
         generate_series('2019-09-01'::timestamp, 
                         greatest(current_date, '2019-09-18'), 
                         interval '1 week') as date ) q
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c22bf64e32ef64543ab4d818b851171b)</kbd>